# Security around user uploaded files

Tags: python, file, web-applications, upload

I have a client's python website which runs a dropbox-like feature that allows uploading of files.

I want to make sure that uploading files does not open up the server to vulnerabilities.

So, I store all uploaded files as blobs in a postgres database and do not trust the file name and extension of the file, I let the application determine that for itself.

[I ran into problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/338087/making-libmagic-file-detect-docx-files) when trying to let the application decide the file format itself, so my question boils down to:

1. Is it necessary, for security, to limit what file formats are allowed to be uploaded?
2. If yes, how, if not using something like `libmagic`, can I determine the file format in the best way?
3. Are there other measures I need to make in order to remain safe when allowing publically loaded files?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? How to detect `docx` without libmagic?

Comment: Security provides assurance that what should happen, happens.  It doesn't exist in a vacuum, it supports application functionality.  If you have a car whose security goal is "don't kill people in a crash", you could solve it by limiting speed to 10mph.  But if it's functional requirements include moving at highway speeds, then security must be achieved some other way.  Do your functional requirements include uploading files of any type?  If so, the needed security mechanisms are more difficult than if you only need to upload image types.  Security can't tell you what your requirements are.

Comment: Requirements: Upload files of common file types, preview, share and download them. Have a server that doesn't leak documents to non-authorized users.

Comment: Then you could define "common" as "file types that my previewer understands".  If you can successfully open and display the file using the previewer, allow it to be uploaded.  If all users are authorized to access the same file types, then you don't need to worry about users lying about the file type to get around the authorizations.  But if some users aren't allowed to download .mp3 files, you have to ensure that .mp3 content is detected regardless of extension, and regardless of whether it's contained in a zip file of a .tgz.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced "bug" question (which chains to [this](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=162526))doesn't refer to a bug, it says that some MS Office file types are, like Java jars, packaged and compressed as zipfiles.  If you rename a .xlsx file to .zip, you can view the contents - I found 13 .xml files and a .bin printer settings file in a simple example.

For security you can't "trust" mime-type and file extension provided by the user, but you can in principle use them to validate that the contents are valid for the claimed file type.  The first level of checking would ensure that the claimed Office files are in fact valid zipfiles, the second would check that the contents conforms to what is expected by the Office application.  Not being an Office developer I don't know of a process to inspect a zip archive, determine which Office application it is for, and validate that the application can open it, but I'm sure it exists somewhere on MSDN.

More fundamentally, what do you mean by "security is important to my application"?  Security prevents unwanted events - you need to define what you want to prevent.  Do you want users to only be able to upload files for whitelisted applications?  Should they be prevented from uploading blacklisted file types (like .exe)?  Is it OK with you if a user uploaded 10MB of random bits and called it a .xyz file?

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote my question. Makes more sense?

Comment: As for the "bug", it is indeed a bug: it's `file` on the server side that determines that the uploaded document is a zip. It may use the zip format but it's really a docx-file, hence why debian has listed it  as an 'outstanding bug'. Patching mime-types would only help if the file was indeed identified as "application/vnd.ms-word.document" or something, which it isn't, during upload.

Comment: For security, comparing the claimed extension with the actual extension is an idea, but seems to include a lot of overhead for lots of different file formats. Would be better to be able to depend on just one or two libs, not lots and lots of routines.

Comment: Is an http: "GET" request really a GET, or is it really a TLS stream, or is it really an IP packet, or is it really an ethernet frame on a LAN?  The answer is, it's all of the above, and more.  Deep packet inspection can have very detailed knowledge of application-specific contents, but it's not a bug to say a TCP packet is a TCP packet, regardless of whether it contains SMTP or HTTP or FTP data.  Similarly, it's not a bug to say a zip file is a zip file, regardless of its contents.  Until magic is extended to support multiple layers of content decoding, it is working as intended.